# orientable manifold with $k$-connected component.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, orientation

> Find how many possible orientation there are for an orientable Manifold with $k$-connected component.

Can we say that , there are $2^{k}$ possible orientation becasue  for all connected component they have 2 orientation ?

Comment: As a related counting problem, how many configurations are possible for $k$ distinguishable coins, each of which can be either heads or tails?

Comment: You mean $k$ connected components. $k$-connected means something totally different.

Comment: no, the manifold is not connected , but they have $k$ -connected component